# Script doesn't show new records it just keep showing the same records

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**Please no jQuery advice**.

This script is designed to show more records from the database if you scroll all the way to the bottom of inside a div call results-container.

The problem I am facing is the same data keeps showing. I notice that if you change the value of a variable call start I notice it will show different sections of data that is

in the users table I just got to find a way where I can change the start variable value constantly every time I make a request for more records to show so I can show different portions of records every time I trigger the

scrollTrigger function starting from the beginning of the database table to the end of the table. I tried many methods to constantly change the start variable value constantly to show different records by each request but I failed, so I removed all the code that wasn't working in the index.php so how can I do this?

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#results-container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 350px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
</style>


<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

var start = 0; //<--The starting location, 0 means to start showing records at the beginning of the database table
var limit =  10;//<--Show 10 records every time you trigger the scrollTrigger function

getData();

//Scrolling to the bottom in the results-container shows more records
document.querySelector('#results-container').addEventListener('scroll',scrollTrigger);

function scrollTrigger(e){
var resultsContainer = e.currentTarget;
  if (Math.ceil(resultsContainer.scrollTop) + resultsContainer.clientHeight >= resultsContainer.scrollHeight) {
    getData();
  }
}
//

function getData(){
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
     document.getElementById('results-container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', xhr.responseText);

//<Allow JS and remove previous appended JS of the requested page>

        Array.prototype.forEach.call( 
        document.querySelectorAll('#results-container script'),
        function(script){
        script.parentNode.removeChild(script)
        eval(script.innerHTML)
    }
)

//</Allow JS and remove previous appended JS of the requested page>

    }
}

    var formData= new FormData();

    formData.append('start',start);
    formData.append('limit',limit);

    xhr.open('POST','data.php')
    xhr.send(formData);

}

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="results-container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php
$servername='localhost';
$username='JD';
$password='1234';
$db_name= 'test';

$connect = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$db_name);

$start = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST['start']);
$limit = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST['limit']);

$query = "SELECT*FROM users LIMIT $start, $limit";

$result= $connect->query($query);

?>
<style>
#number{
    background-color: gold;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}

h2{
display: inline-block;
}

</style>

<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

<h2 id='number' ><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></h2>
<h2><?php echo $row['username']; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $row['password']; ?></p>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you never change the value of start, so why would it return anything different?

Comment: Thanks for your response and I know that I took out the code that was not working I said it in the description I just need advice on how I can constantly change the start variable value constantly when I make a request to get more records do you know how that can be possible ?

Comment: can you just do start += limit in your onreadystatechange handler?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Can you give a code example what you mean by what your saying?

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript, you did not change the value of `start` and `limit`. Therefore you are always sending the same start and limit to your server.

To change it, you can recalculate the values of `start` and `limit` after you get the result back from server and after updating the DOM (after `eval`):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

var start = 0; //<--The starting location, 0 means to start showing records at the beginning of the database table
var limit =  10;//<--Show 10 records every time you trigger the scrollTrigger function

getData();

//Scrolling to the bottom in the results-container shows more records
document.querySelector('#results-container').addEventListener('scroll',scrollTrigger);

function scrollTrigger(e){
var resultsContainer = e.currentTarget;
  if (Math.ceil(resultsContainer.scrollTop) + resultsContainer.clientHeight >= resultsContainer.scrollHeight) {
    getData();
  }
}
//

function getData(){
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
     document.getElementById('results-container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', xhr.responseText);

//<Allow JS and remove previous appended JS of the requested page>

        Array.prototype.forEach.call( 
        document.querySelectorAll('#results-container script'),
        function(script){
        script.parentNode.removeChild(script)
        eval(script.innerHTML)

        /* HERE */
        start = limit;
        limit = start + 10;
    }
)

//</Allow JS and remove previous appended JS of the requested page>

    }
}

    var formData= new FormData();

    formData.append('start',start);
    formData.append('limit',limit);

    xhr.open('POST','data.php')
    xhr.send(formData);

}

});
```

Comment: Hello Yong Quan thanks for  your response I tried your code advice and it still give the same results it shows the results from 1-10 then when I scroll all the way down to trigger the scrollTrigger function. It shows another group 1-10 the same records do you know what could have gone wrong?

Comment: I don't think limit needs to change. That is passed to mysql and just specifies the number of results to return.

Comment: might need to add ORDER BY to the mysql query so the users are queried in same order each time. If unordered, results may be random.